# Phoenix-hbase can't execute upsert query through jdbc

Tags: jdbc, hbase, apache-phoenix

Firstly I want to clarify that create query is working fine.

when doing the following: query 1 & query 3 results in error on executing query 3 but query 2 & 3 works fine.I can't find anythong on the net.

```
class test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Connection connection;
        try {
            Class.forName("org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:phoenix:localhost:2181/hbase-insecure");
        //(note:i have tried without /hbase - insecure the result is same)

//query 1:-> 
        connection.createStatement().executeUpdate("UPSERT INTO tableName VALUES('1','randomValue','randomValue',1234567890, 'randomValue', 'randomValue')");

//query 2:->
        connection.createStatement().executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tableName (A VARCHAR(40), Z.B.type VARCHAR, Z.C VARCHAR, Z.D UNSIGNED_LONG, Z.E VARCHAR,X.F VARCHAR CONSTRAINT rowkey PRIMARY KEY (A))");

//query 3:-> 
        connection.commit();
    }
}
```

> error:Exception in thread "streaming-job-executor-0"
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.KeyValueUtil.length(Lorg/apache/hadoop/hbase/Cell;)I
>   at
>   org.apache.phoenix.util.PhoenixKeyValueUtil.calculateMutationDiskSize(PhoenixKeyValueUtil.java:182)
>   at
>   org.apache.phoenix.execute.MutationState.calculateMutationSize(MutationState.java:800)
>   at
>   org.apache.phoenix.execute.MutationState.send(MutationState.java:971)
>   at
>   org.apache.phoenix.execute.MutationState.send(MutationState.java:1344)
>   at
>   org.apache.phoenix.execute.MutationState.commit(MutationState.java:1167)
>   at
>   org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixConnection$3.call(PhoenixConnection.java:670)
>   at
>   org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixConnection$3.call(PhoenixConnection.java:666)
>   at org.apache.phoenix.call.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:53) at
>   org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixConnection.commit(PhoenixConnection.java:666)
>   at
>   com.kratinmobile.uep.services.SparkStream.lambda$null$0(SparkStream.java:119)
>   at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) at
>   com.kratinmobile.uep.services.SparkStream.lambda$startStreaming$10899135$1(SparkStream.java:102)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStreamLike$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1.apply(JavaDStreamLike.scala:272)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStreamLike$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1.apply(JavaDStreamLike.scala:272)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:628)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:628)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:416)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
>   at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192) at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:39) at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:257)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:257)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:257)
>   at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58) at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:256)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: looks most likely to be a jar file mismatch or version mismatch. I see traces of apache spark, Are you using apache spark ?

Comment: I'm using spark libraries. and just realized you are right this is a version mismatch. I don't know why but Phoenix hasn't released a version compatible to HBase 2.2 as of now up till HBase 2.0 is compatible. Thank You for your reply. Can you answer this question with same response as your comment so that I can mark it as the anwer.

Comment: Sure thing, done. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the stack trace it most likely looks like a classpath mistmatch or a version mismatch.